# How to get first day of specific month & year in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to get the first day of the specific year and month. This is my request data which comes to controller

```
 "month" => "August"
 "year" => "2020"
```

I'm trying to get the first day of that specific month and year by doing this way

```
         Carbon::parse($request->month)->firstOfMonth();
```

It gives first day of month properly but year is not correct. It always shows year 2021. I want to get year 2020, month august 1st day data.

What is correct way to get the?

Comment: You only parse `$request->month`, so the current year is taken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only passing the month name into the `parse()` method. How do you expect `Carbon` to know the year?

```php
Carbon::createFromFormat('F Y', $request->month.' '.$request->year)->firstOfMonth();
```

Comment: I didn't pass the year because I don't know the proper way. That's why I make question here. Thanks a lot

Comment: Didn't mean to be rude if you thought, I was. Sorry if my answer sounded that was. It was meant to be more of a rhetorical question. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your custom year in carbon:

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::parse($request->month)->setYear(2020)->firstOfMonth();
```